# Conditional Join or ignore results when second value is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've tried to focus on just the portion of my main query giving me trouble.  This query is being used to populate an SSRS report which has an optional date parameter.  This query snippet is used in a LEFT Join.  If no date is specified, all matching records should be returned.  That seems to work.  But if I specify a date and no records are returned in the second column, no results for that row should be displayed.  Not sure if I explained that well.

Here is the snippet:

```
DECLARE @DispoStartDt datetime, @DispoEndDt datetime, @DispoCode varchar(800)
SET @DispoStartDt = '5-1-2050'
--SET @DispoEndDt = '12-31-2014'
SET @DispoCode = '_NULL'

SELECT  c1.CaseID,
        STUFF((SELECT '; ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ct.DispoDt, 101)
                FROM jw50_CountInvPers ct
                WHERE ct.CaseID = '00-100'
                AND     (ct.DispoDt >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, ISNULL(@DispoStartDt, ct.DispoDt)), 0) AND ct.DispoDt < DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, -1, ISNULL(@DispoEndDt, ct.DispoDt)), 0))

                ORDER BY DispoDesc
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [DispoDts]
FROM    jw50_Case c1
WHERE c1.CaseID = '00-100'
GROUP BY    c1.CaseID
```

My results are:

```
CaseID     DispoDts
 00-100      NULL
```

I want no records returned if DispoDts is NULL.  Since I cannot reference a column alias, is there another way than putting this in a sub select?

**EDIT:**

Here is the snippet used in my Join.  I'm getting rows with NULL DispoDts because of the left join.  If I specify a start date, I want the results to be treated like an inner join, only return results where they match a join row.  If I don't specify a date, give me everything in the main table if a join exists or not.

```
DECLARE @DispoStartDt datetime, @DispoEndDt datetime, @DispoCode varchar(800)
SET @DispoStartDt = '5-1-2015'
--SET @DispoEndDt = '12-31-2014'
SET @DispoCode = '_NULL'

SELECT    c.CaseID
        , c.ProsNum AS FileNum
        , c.CaseStatusDesc AS CaseStatus
        , disp.DispoDts
FROM    jw50_Case c
    LEFT JOIN   (SELECT CaseID, DispoDts
                 FROM   (
                            SELECT  c1.CaseID,
                                STUFF((SELECT '; ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ct.DispoDt, 101)
                                        FROM jw50_CountInvPers ct
                                        WHERE ct.CaseID = c1.CaseId
                                            AND     (ct.DispoDt >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, ISNULL(@DispoStartDt, ct.DispoDt)), 0) AND ct.DispoDt < DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, -1, ISNULL(@DispoEndDt, ct.DispoDt)), 0))

                                    ORDER BY DispoDesc
                                    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [DispoDts]
                    FROM    jw50_Case c1
                    WHERE c1.CaseID = c1.CaseId
                    GROUP BY    c1.CaseID
                    ) a
             WHERE DispoDts IS NOT NULL
) disp ON disp.CaseID = c.CaseID
ORDER BY    CaseID, DispoDts
```

**EDIT 2:**

Ok, feels dirty, but it works.

```
WHERE (@DispoStartDt IS NULL AND @DispoEndDt IS NULL)
    OR (@DispoStartDt IS NOT NULL AND @DispoEndDt IS NOT NULL AND disp.DispoDts IS NOT NULL)
    OR (@DispoStartDt IS NOT NULL AND @DispoEndDt IS NULL AND disp.DispoDts IS NOT NULL)
    OR (@DispoStartDt IS NULL AND @DispoEndDt IS NOT NULL AND disp.DispoDts IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
DECLARE @DispoStartDt datetime, @DispoEndDt datetime, @DispoCode varchar(800)
SET @DispoStartDt = '5-1-2050'
--SET @DispoEndDt = '12-31-2014'
SET @DispoCode = '_NULL'

SELECT CaseID,
        [DispoDts]
FROM (
    SELECT  c1.CaseID,
            STUFF((SELECT '; ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ct.DispoDt, 101)
                    FROM jw50_CountInvPers ct
                    WHERE ct.CaseID = '00-100'
                    AND     (ct.DispoDt >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, ISNULL(@DispoStartDt, ct.DispoDt)), 0) AND ct.DispoDt < DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, -1, ISNULL(@DispoEndDt, ct.DispoDt)), 0))

                    ORDER BY DispoDesc
                    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [DispoDts]
    FROM    jw50_Case c1
    WHERE c1.CaseID = '00-100'
    GROUP BY    c1.CaseID
) as tbaux
WHERE [DispoDts] IS NOT NULL
```

This way you get the same values ​​as before, but the result is passed to a query above which validates the `DispoDts`

And this way ?

```
    DECLARE @DispoStartDt datetime, @DispoEndDt datetime, @DispoCode varchar(800)
    SET @DispoStartDt = '5-1-2015'
    --SET @DispoEndDt = '12-31-2014'
    SET @DispoCode = '_NULL'

    SELECT    c.CaseID
            , c.ProsNum AS FileNum
            , c.CaseStatusDesc AS CaseStatus
            , disp.DispoDts
    FROM jw50_Case c
        LEFT JOIN   (SELECT  c1.CaseID,
                              STUFF((SELECT '; ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ct.DispoDt, 101)
                                      FROM jw50_CountInvPers ct
                                      WHERE ct.CaseID = c1.CaseId
                                        AND     (ct.DispoDt >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, ISNULL(@DispoStartDt, ct.DispoDt)), 0) AND ct.DispoDt < DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, -1, ISNULL(@DispoEndDt, ct.DispoDt)), 0))
                                      ORDER BY DispoDesc
                                      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [DispoDts]
                      FROM jw50_Case c1
                      WHERE c1.CaseID = c1.CaseId
                      GROUP BY c1.CaseID
         ) disp ON disp.CaseID = c.CaseID
    WHERE @DispoEndDt IS NULL OR disp.DispoDts IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY CaseID, DispoDts
```

Comment: Still not quite right.  The optional dates are really giving me heartburn.

Comment: Ok, getting closer, making sense.  Now to work in the other scenarios:  both dates provided, only the end date provided.  Just wondering how complex I need to make that final Where.

Comment: Ok, improved? my Where.  Seems ugly, but hey, it works.  Now to figure out how to sort the final result by the order of the Join table.  If I just do Order By disp.DispoDts I get an alpha sort of the resulting string of dates.  I need to sort by the original date value.